# Gateway timeout while installing Jboss tools in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I am trying to add a JBoss server in my eclipse 2021-03 and encountered some issues. However, there is a gateway timeout error when I try to install JBoss tools via Eclipse Marketplace.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrD5f.jpg)
Also, I have encountered another timeout error when I am trying to install Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7.2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANisG.png)
I would appreciate it if anyone could help, I have no idea how to fix this

Comment: also having this problem

Comment: I am having this problem too

Comment: I did more tests with https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/stable/updates/ 
My home connection cannot access it. My phone can access it. kproxy.com can access it. Non Jboss.org stuff do not have the issue.

Comment: Today it works for me, probably they had problem at jboss with their servers.